# Create shake movement in IPhone application

Tags: iphone

I want to create an application using shaking. That is when I shake my IPad, then the icon will be move automatically depends upon shaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use accelerometer datas.

Take a look at CoreMotion API http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CoreMotion_Reference/_index.html

It's an easy way to use acce / gyro & co datas :-)